# Python: what does putting [square] brackets around an object do?

Tags: python, object, initialization, brackets

I'm translating code from Python to Lua, but I can't figure out what this line of code does:

`results = [node]`

To provide context, this is in the parser for a Pascal interpreter. I'm translating this code from a tutorial to try to wrap my head around interpreters. node is an object that represents a node in an abstract syntax tree. I'm not sure what the brackets do.

[Here](https://github.com/rspivak/lsbasi/blob/master/part9/python/spi.py) is the full code for the interpreter at this point in the tutorial. The line I'm looking at is 255.

Comment: Syntax seems to suggest that it's populating a list https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: The variable node is a reference to an object, not the object itself.  `[node]` is forming a single element list containing that reference.  `results` is set to reference that single element list.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic (footnote A) but "brackets" is a general term for anything that brackets something. That would include square brackets (what you're asking about), parentheses, braces, and probably other things. It would possibly be better if you were more specific in your title. Footnote A: I'm really not, it's just in my nature, annoying though that is to neurotypicals :-)

Comment: paxdiablo I've always referred to them as parenthesis, brackets, and braces, but if brackets is a general term, I'll just say square brackets. Maybe they all should be shapes: circle brackets, square brackets, and ??? brackets. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That creates a list of one element with just the `node` object. Presumably `results` is expected to be a list.

Comment: vonbrand that makes a lot of sense. I'll come back later either to resolve this or report if it didn't work.

Comment: Other than the fact these are called lists rather than arrays in Python, a good answer. Making that small change.